# JQuery hide priority over show?

Tags: jquery

I'm having an issue with JQuery show and hide.  When I hover over an element, I want to show another element pop out to the right.  I have managed that with the following code:

```
var actionHoverInListener = function () {
    $(this).children('.pop-out').show("slide", { direction:"left" }, 100);
};
var actionHoverOutListener = function () {
    $(this).children('.pop-out').hide("slide", { direction:"left" }, 100);
};

// Add a hover listener for actions
$(".magic").hover(
    actionHoverInListener, actionHoverOutListener
);
```

This works fine, but the issue is speed.  If I hover over and out of the "magic" div too quickly, it never hides the popout.  It's as if the hide call is ignored because the show is still animating the slide.

The hover out method is being called correctly: I have put in logging code to make sure it is getting called.  So, the problem is that the hide does not cancel the show.  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

I have included an example of my problem on jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Pekf2/

Run your mouse down the red stripes.  You will see the green slide out, but not slide back if you're too fast (even with the stop() call).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to

```
$(this).children('.pop-out').stop().hide(...
```

This will stop the show animation and hide immediately.

EDIT:  Not exactly sure why, but `.stop` does not play nice with `.children` like that. Using different selector syntax seems to make it work for whatever reason.

Additionally, since the animation is halted, it's possible for the `left` CSS to become negative, so I added a callback on the `.hide` to set it to 0 once it's complete.

http://jsfiddle.net/Pekf2/4/

Comment: This didn't work for me unfortunately.  I'm putting something together on jsfiddle.net to show the problem.

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle sample (with stop()) which still doesn't work.  I'd appreciate it if you had any other suggestions!

Comment: Thanks Explosion Pills - changing the selector and not using .children() made it work perfectly.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using the [jQuery hoverintent plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) – it's solved issues like this for me before.

Fiddling with your fiddle and implementing hoverIntent brought me to this: http://jsfiddle.net/crowjonah/Pekf2/1/

Works pretty well if I do say so. I just changed the script to accomodate for the plugin like so:

```
var config = {    
 over: actionHoverInListener, // function = onMouseOver callback (REQUIRED)    
 timeout: 1000, // number = milliseconds delay before onMouseOut    
 out: actionHoverOutListener // function = onMouseOut callback (REQUIRED)
```

};

```
// Add a hover listener for actions
   $('.monkey').hoverIntent(
       config
);
```